# Mandatory validation for a subset of properties using data annotation

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

I have a DTO model which contains three fields.

```
[Range(1, 100000)]
public Decimal? BonusRate { get; set; }
[Range(1, 100000)]
public Decimal? BonusGain { get; set; }
[Range(1, 100)]
public Decimal? BonusPercentage { get; set; }
```

In my case all fields are optional, but if one is set all others should be set too. I have worked out a decision and it works well, but looks a little clumsy.

```
IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (BonusRate.HasValue || BonusGain.HasValue || BonusPercentage.HasValue)
        if (!BonusRate.HasValue || !BonusGain.HasValue || !BonusPercentage.HasValue)
             yield return new ValidationResult("message");

}
```

Does anybody know a better approach?

Comment: You could use some implementation of RequiredIf attribute but for simple case I think it is an overkill.

Comment: I think about it. I can create a read-only property IsBonusRequired and use RequiredIf attribute. So it helps to remove one condition, but it requires an extra nuget package. It will be more suitable if  you are already use it.

Comment: Yeah, that's way I said it is an overkill. Another option would be using different DTOs for different logic(one with nullable properties, one with not nullable). I don't know details of your implementation so it is hard to say if it is viable :)

Comment: You might consider using [foolproof](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/). That library has some required attributes that would make this easy work. For instance, you could chain `[RequiredIfNotEmpty]` so that when one is supplied, the other two are required.

Comment: I have look at implementation of this function [here](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof/blob/master/Foolproof/RequiredIfNotEmpty.cs) and  figured out that there are no opportunity to push a list of dependable properties (only one).

Comment: Honestly, there's nothing truly wrong with your implementation. Remember that other human being will likely have to read your code one day, so there's a cost in getting extra fancy with "clever" code tricks. Your code is very clear to understand for any developer coming into the solution. As for performance, nothing suggested will be remarkably different (although collecting them into a list would probably be microscopically worse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches and your advices I have found a general strategy. 
Are you free to use external packages?

**Yes**

1. Add [foolproof](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/) library to a solution
2. Create a readonly property `IsGroupRequired` like

   ```
   public Boolean IsGroupRequired
   {
       get
       {
           return GroupItem1.HasValue == GroupItem2.HasValue
               && GroupItem2.HasValue == GroupItem3.HasValue
               && GroupItemNminus1.HasValue == GroupItemN.HasValue;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Assign `[RequiredIfTrue("IsGroupRequired")]` for an each property of the group `GroupItem1..N`

**No**

1. Implement an `IValidatableObject` interface for your model
2. Write your own validation method

   ```
   IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
   {
       if (GroupItem1.HasValue == GroupItem2.HasValue
           && GroupItem2.HasValue == GroupItem3.HasValue
           && GroupItemN.HasValue == GroupItemN+1.HasValue)
               yield return new ValidationResult("Your message goes here");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (BonusRate.HasValue == BonusGain.HasValue && BonusGain.HasValue == BonusPercentage.HasValue)
```

or collect values in a list and:

```
var isChecked = list.All(x => (x == list.First()));
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate why either of these are a better solution? All I see is extra overhead (for the list) and/or overly complex/fancy syntax to do the same thing as the OP.

Comment: goal: to have three boolean variables in same status, my solution aims to this. we need at least three check for verify this (like 1st variant). 2nd variant worse but laconic.

Comment: Look at my answer. If you write conditions in a column it will be more readable and I have figured out general pattern. If you have ten properties in a group and batch import with 1000 models and 1000 users can do this import. Reduce extra condition can really be helpful.